# Getting 10 coefficients for notch filter(butterworth stop band ) of filter order 2. Why so many coefficients

Tags: filters

Implemented butterworth stopband(notch) filter, order is 2
Getting total 10 coefficients,
Designed in matlab.
Can you please explain why I am getting 10 coefficients

Comment: Without showing the actual steps nobody can know what you have in your mind or in front of you and, thus, nobody can give a clear answer.

Answer (score -1):

A way to design band pass/reject filters is by [Bandform transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype_filter#Lowpass_to_bandstop), basically you design a low pass filter and replace $s$ in the transfer function by an expression.

Since you will replace $i \omega$ by $\omega_c'/\frac{\omega_0}{ \Delta \omega} \left(\frac{i \omega}{\omega_0} + \frac{\omega_0}{i \omega} \right) = \frac{\omega_c' \, \Delta \omega \, \omega_0 \, i \omega}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2}$, the degree of your transfer function will be twice the degree of your filter.

The procedure adopted by matlab may be different, but the idea is: If your filter has order 2, and we apply this transformation, both the numerator and the denominator of the transfer function will end up being fourth order polynomials, thus, having 5 coefficient each. In total, 10 scalars are used to describe your filter.

Comment: If 10 unique scalers are defining this IIR filter, it's order 4.  Not order 2.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson You're right about the order, but OP might be referring to the actual coefficients, not the order (i.e. language barrier). But I can't be sure given OP's terse question.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson, check what happens when you apply the band transformation to a second order low-pass filter. Strictly speaking you could describe with 9 coefficient (a gain and two monic 4 degree polynomials).

Comment: That is certainly true, Bob.  You might wanna check out the [Audio EQ Cookbook](https://www.w3.org/TR/audio-eq-cookbook/).  The third equation (they are not numbered in that w3 version) has the overall gain factored out.  For each order of an IIR filter, the number of independent parameters or controls is 2 per order and 1 more for overall gain.